# Is Thymeleaf necessary or useful with spring boot and reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would have thought that react alone would be sufficient for the front end of a spring boot application but examples I have seen use also Thymeleaf. Can Thhymeleaf be eliminated? But if so, is it still useful?

Comment: Both technologies are completely different. React provides so much, however Thymeleaf is just a template rendering library. If you want to make career in FE then learn React/Angular/Vue.. if you just want to build a crud with minimal learning curve then only go for Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf is not necessary for a Spring Boot/React application. You can serve up standard HTML files and add whatever ids that are necessary for your react project in those HTML files. You can serve up an HTML file from your src/main/resources/templates/ folder like so:

```java
/**
 * Returns the home page.
 * 
 * @return index
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHomePage() {
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: why is HTML serving needed if u use reactjs -- why does the backend have to do anything for the frontend other than to provide data?

Comment: The backend doesn't need to do anything with html, reactjs, or thymeleaf if you only plan on serving up data to the frontend. But, if you do plan on serving non data content, then you'll likely need to serve up some html page, which there you could include some react component.